# Working around the lack of co/contravariance in IDictionary<TKey, TValue>

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, casting, covariance

I have a low level class that has a property like this:

```
public IDictionary<IHttpParam, IHttpArg> Parameters {get;}
```

One my higher level classes uses this class, but also exposes it's own property called Parameters, but with a different type:

```
public IDictionary<CommandParameter, ICommandArgument> Parameters {get;}
```

CommandParameter implements the IHttpParam interface, and ICommandArgument extends the IHttpArg interface, so ideally, I would love to be able to implement it like this:

```
public IDictionary<CommandParameter, ICommandArgument> Parameters { get { return this.httpReq.Parameters; } }
```

This is unfortunately impossible because of the lack of co/contravariance on the IDictionary interface.  I understand the technical reasons why it cannot support this language feature, but what is the best way to work around this?

I suppose one option would be to create and return a wrapper `IDictionary<TKey, TVal>` that converts all calls to the `IDictionary<CommandParameter, ICommandArgument>` to a call to the underlying IDictionary.  The wrapper would implement this through lots of casts from one interface to another though, which I think could harm performance.  Is there a better solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write some method like `public ICommandArgument GetParameter(CommandParameter param)`, or implement the `Parameters` dictionary in some other lazy way, as a function. Unfortunately I can't see any way around the casting, but I don't think the performance penalty is so high here. You're dealing with HTTP, so casting will hardly be the bottleneck.

Comment: Quite fair.  I was hoping there would be a way to pass the underlying dictionary back transparently with no performance hits at all, but in the grand scale of things, I don't think this will create much of a hit.